# Can I run wire from my meter to a shed for a subpanel?

Tags: wiring

I want to wire my shed for 100amp. My breaker box in house has no more space. Can i run wire from my outdoor meter on the side of the house under ground to 100 amp breaker box in the shed

Comment: I'd vote NO on this one.  You could... maybe... run the line from YOUR side of the master breaker on the breaker box out to a new breaker box in the shed, but 100A is a lot. What is your current house service?

Comment: There are ways of doing what you want, but this is not it. We'll need more details on your current setup, including service capacity (ask your utility), location of meter and current breaker panel, length of run to shed, why you want 100A to your shed, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Comment: @FreeMan 'abandoned' is not a close vote reason. Does the question need more detail? Does it need more focus? Use the appropriate prescribed reason instead. If a question is drawing low-quality answers, instead of voting to close it, protect the question, instead, or flag it to be protected by a moderator if you don't have sufficient reputation. In the meantime, downvote the low-quality answer if appropriate. But don't punish the question for a poor answer.

Comment: It's an old question that's likely to _never_ get an accepted answer. Granted, the system won't bump this one (the late "possibly-but-not-likely-an-answer" bumped it to the top), but it doesn't hurt to do some clean up. With only 21 rep at the moment, the OP probably doesn't give a hoot about points or being "punished", especially since his last visit was 2 weeks after this question was posted. I suppose I could have said "...because I'm trying to help clean up old questions", but what I put was shorter...

Answer (score 3):

No, the cabling run from service to shed needs to have overcurrent protection.   Your local authority might allow it under the *tap rules*, given a pretty good reason... But "out of space in my panel" definitely won't qualify.

It sounds like you should start with a subpanel in your *home* to move the smaller loads out of your main panel.  This is a big job like the Platte river is wide (but not very deep).  And it's very DIYable at sane cost. It will set you back a panel (some of which come with free breakers), a big double breaker, and some breakers if your new panel uses a different type (which may be a good idea if your current panel is a builder-grade cheapie, or if GFCI and AFCI breakers are unduly expensive for your panel.)  And of course wire and the odd junction box or bit of conduit.

If your existing cables are too short to reach the new subpanel, install new junction boxes to where they *can* reach.  Splice them there onto some more cable to the new box. Bonus points if you can make the box-to-panel run in conduit; but only 4 circuits are allowed per conduit.

Get the biggest panel you can fit; a few extra spaces are cheap, and often even come with more free breakers.  60 spaces is not too large.

Leave your main panel feeding only large loads and subpanels.

Comment: That's all great advice... But 100A service is a whole house for some folks.. I suspect he is trying to set up a machine shop. In which case he really should get a whole new service installed.

Comment: I wouldn't say "should" for that.   One problem with another service is another monthly service charge. Least I've seen is $10, most is $35; either way that means a reasonable payback period for the *materials* he'd need.  I'd say "should" for the max'd out main panel -- that is a big inconvenience that motivates mistakes, shortcuts and bad practice (like tapping meters).

Comment: Ya I meant if he currently has 100A service, get it upgraded to 200A @Harper

Comment: Definitely agreed.   I assumed he knows his main panel is more than 100A, and is not looking for a subpanel the same current as his main panel.

Comment: ,, I stopped assuming anything on here LOL... Have you read some of the questions....